# Kendo Scheduler TimeLine Event Height issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, timeline, kendo-scheduler

I am using the Kendo scheduler UI (Timeline view) in .net based MVC application. I have observed that there are some diff in the row height and the event height. I hve a requirement to make it aligned so as to remove the white space.  Kindly let me know if this can be done.[image]

Answer (score 0):

First set

**eventHeight: 15**

in the scheduler

and then add below CSS

```
  .k-event-inverse {
        height: 25px !important;
    }
```